# How do I get Google Calendar event invitations through the Calendar app for Android?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

In the webapp's settings, there's the option for email or SMS. In the Android settings, there's no option for event invitation notifications.

Is there a way to just get a notification from the Calendar app and no email?